# Distributed Transactional Memory with Zookeeper / Hadoop?

Tags: java, memory, transactions, distributed

I am looking for a Java solution beside big memory and hazelcast. Since we are using Hadoop/Spark we should have access to Zookeeper.

So I just want to know if there is a solution satisfying our needs or do we need to build something ourself.

What I need are reliable objects that are inmemory, replicated and synchronized. For manipulation I would like to have lock support and atomic actions spanning an object.

I also need support for object references and List/Set/Map support.

The rest we can build on ourself.

The idea is simply having self organizing network that configures itself based on the environment and that is best done by synchronized objects that are replicated and one can listen to.

Comment: So what is the question? Why don't you want to use hazelcast?

Comment: Hazelcast is way over the top and I am not convinced that they have the split brain problem in check. I need a solution where the server shoot themself in the head if that happens and I wont be able to game hazelcast to do so.

Comment: What solution to the split brain problem would you prefer to see?

Comment: A quorum where once a node leaves the nodes active are counted and if it reaches a certain minimum n/2-1 -> Every node stops working. So there is a guarantee that if the unthinkable happens (n+1 dies) the system stops working.

Comment: All you need is half your systems in the same data centre and you will get a quorum failing.  If you want resilience you need a quorum of data centres as well.

Comment: We are currently not planing to go the wan thing. It is not on the list. We will have three independent networks with the same specs and those networks exchange just messages no sync.

Answer (score 1):

Hazelcast, has a split-brain detector in place and when split-brain happens hazelcast will continue to accept updates and when the cluster is merged back, it will give you an ability to merge the updates that you preferred.

We are implementing a cluster quorum feature, which will hopefully available in the next minor (3.5) version. With cluster quorum you can define a minimum threshold or a custom function of your own to decide whether cluster should continue to operate or not in a partitioned network.

For example, if you define a quorum size of 3, if there is a less than 3 members in the cluster, the cluster will stop operating.

Currently hazelcast behaves like an AP solution, but when the cluster quorum is available you can tune hazelcast to behave like a CP solution.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any idea when the 3.5 version will hit the street?

Comment: It is planned to be released in May.